# How to bind Grid RowDefinition's Height in X.F?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this binding in my XAML

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding HasValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToIntConverter}, ConverterParameter=33}" />
```

but it doesn't seem to work as straight-forward as I assumed. When rendering the page the height of the row is evaluated to a star value actually as opposed to 33.

Any trick I am missing?

Comment: For the ConverterParameter include the type, like so: `ConverterParameter={x:Int32 33}`

Answer (score 0):

The binding works if the converter returns a value of type `GridLength` explicitly...